# size of the collection of all formulas under a countable language is $\aleph_0$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a countable language.

I want to show the size of the collection of all $L$-formulas is precisely $\aleph_0$.

Attempt:

I know by definition an atomic $L$-formula obtained by equating or relating $L$-terms.

So I want to show the the size of the collection of $L$-terms is countable, where the $L$-terms can be a variable, a constant, or function of other $L$-terms.

But now I'm not sure what to do next.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The set of all finite sequences of elements of a countable set is countable.

Comment: @Sam This proves that the size is at most $\aleph_0$. How does one show that it is at least $\aleph_0$ if $L$ is finite? (I assume here that countable means finite or countably infinite)

Comment: @John You can use a function or relation symbol and iterate forever: $f(x), f(f(x)), ....$ or $R(x_1,...x_n), \neg R(x_1,...,x_n), \neg\neg R(x_1,...,x_n)$, etc. Of course this only works if $L$ has function and/or relation symbols. Otherwise the set of atomic formulas is empty, but that's just one single extreme case.

Comment: @Sam The set of atomic formulas always contains $x=x$. So you can take $x = x$, $x = x\land x = x$, $x = x \land  x = x\land x = x$, etc.